# Error when installing a python module in Linux

Tags: numpy, pip

I am encoutering two kinds of issues while trying to install a package called Boltztrap2.

1) Trying to install [Boltztrap2](https://pypi.org/project/BoltzTraP2/) using 'pip3'. However, when I punch in the command, the process goes smoothly for a while and then spits out an error :

```
BoltzTraP2/sphere/frontend.cpp:32:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I did some troubleshooting and found out that it is just a path issue - I confirmed this by typing 'locate Python.h'. However, I don't get how to manually incorporate this change since the 'pip3' command that I use downloads the program and compiles it automatically. I don't seem to have access to change any scripts, or rather I do not know how to, since I'm kind of new to all this.

PS: I do not have sudo access.

2) Trying to install Boltztrap2 by manually compiling the python setup file: This seems to work fine until the system spits out an error saying:

Error:numpy is not installed.

PS: Again, I do not have sudo access.

I would be very glad if someone could help me install this package through either method. I just want to get the software to work. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install numpy
```

Check if you can upgrade pip?
If that works then you can pip install numpy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
'python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' doesn't work - I am getting a permission error:permission denied. 
'pip3 install numpy' works I think. It says requirement already satisfied. But this doesn't solve the problem I am having (either method 1 or method 2)..

Comment: It seems like Python isn't installed properly, and to reinstall it you'd need sudo access. Is there any way you can reinstall python?

Comment: I'm trying to reach out to the moderators of my university's supercomputer. They've been slow in responding but at present, I can't seem to resolve this issue.

Comment: I researched a bit about your issue, I think reinstalling python is the only way to do it, because even manually adding that header file would require sudo access.

Comment: Thanks @Rohan Mukherjee. Will comment here if the issue is resolved.

Comment: I was able to successfully install the package but it looks like it needs to be added onto PATH. How should do I go about doing this? I know it has to do something with editing the .bashrc file?

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin
This is how you normally add to PATH.
Did it not get added to PATH on it's own upon installation?

Comment: No. I added it in manually. It works now. So the problem was with loading the right python module .. I just loaded the anaconda module and used pip to install it locally and it worked! Thanks!